# Create dynamic scopes based on other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails (5.0) app, I have the following

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :zone, optional: false
end

class Zone < ApplicationRecord
  scope :lines, -> { where(kind: 'line') }
end
```

Now I need to define in `Batch` a scope for each `Zone` which is a line. Something like the code below works.

```
  Zone.lines.map(&:name).each do |name|
    scope "manufactured_on_#{name}".to_sym, -> { joins(:zone).where("zones.name = '#{name}'") }
  end
```

The issue is that the code above is evaluated when the app boots and at that time the scopes are created. If I add a new`Zone` of kind `line`, the scope is not created.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the zone's name as a scope param

```
scope :manufactured_on, -> (name) { joins(:zone).where(zones: { name: name } ) }
```

Comment: As an aside, the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) note that: *Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.*

Answer (score 0):

You can look into documentation and search for `method_missing`.

But this does not seem a good approach to me.

Instead, define scope in following way:

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord
  scope :manufactured_on, ->(line) { joins(:zone).where("zones.name = '#{name}'") }
end
```

Then simply use

```
Batch.manufactured_on(zone.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of the possibility to pass params and that would be my first approach. however, due to the way params come in, it would be much easier to have multiple scopes.

Comment: Defining scopes based on parameters coming in sounds like a security issue to me. Also that would introduce unnecessary complexity (maintain scopes in sync with db records). On the other hand, just parse/otherwise process the params and use the existing mechanisms (parameterized scopes), it seems much more straighforward.

Comment: I agree, because of that, I'm working on updating how params are passed in.

Comment: @Sig, you can totally define scopes based on value of name (or anything), like: `scope :manufactured_on_delhi, -> { manufactured_on('delhi') }`. But they will all be **static**.

Comment: As an aside, the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) note that: *Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.*

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the scope name to be dynamic you can use [method_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) as below:

```
class Batch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :zone, optional: false

  def self.method_missing(name, *args)
    method_name = name.to_s

    if method_name.start_with?('manufactured_on_')
      zone_name = method_name.split('manufactured_on_')[1]
      joins(:zone).where(zones: { name: zone_name } )
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.respond_to_missing?(name, include_private = false)
    name.to_s.start_with?('manufactured_on_') || super
  end
end
```

Now, you can call this scope as normal:

```
Batch.manufactured_on_zone_a
```

Comment: Thanks., however I have already implemented the scope with argument.